# pandas/openpyxl: zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am using Pandas v.1.2.2. I do get a `zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` when trying to open a newly created `test.xlsx` file with `openpyxl`.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx") as writer:
    load_workbook(writer)
```

Here' the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/D292498/PycharmProjects/sov_rating/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    load_workbook(writer)
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\zipfile.py", line 1336, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/D292498/PycharmProjects/sov_rating/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    load_workbook(writer)
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 894, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 898, in close
    content = self.save()
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 54, in save
    self.book.save(self.handles.handle)
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 392, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 89, in write_data
    archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK, writer.write())
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\_writer.py", line 148, in write
    self.write_views()
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\_writer.py", line 135, in write_views
    active = get_active_sheet(self.wb)
  File "C:\Users\D292498\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\sov_rating_py38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\_writer.py", line 33, in get_active_sheet
    raise IndexError("At least one sheet must be visible")
IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
```